# How to know a specific printer errors and how to handle them?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a simple project where I want to know the available printers, then connect to one of them and see if there are errors or not.
I have used QPrinterInfo class in order to know the available printer names, then in order to work with one of the available printers, I set its name using "printer.setPrinterName("desired printer name")".
In order to know if there are some errors related to this printer (named as  desired printer name), I searched and find out I have to use QPrinter::Error and then handle the errors.
My question is that what kinds of error can occur when using QPrinter::Error inside my if statement(in the following code)? If no papers exists inside the printer, will using QPrinter::Error throw an error? In general, how can I know what kinds of error I can handle and how to handle them?

code:

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinterInfo>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
#include <QList>


 namespace Ui {
   class MainWindow;
 }

 class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
 {
   Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();


    QPrinter printer;


private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);



QPrinterInfo PrinterInfo;
qDebug() << QStringList(QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames());
if (QPrinterInfo::availablePrinterNames().isEmpty())
{
    qDebug() << " printer not found ";
}


printer.setPrinterName("desired printer name");
if (printer.printerState() == QPrinter::Error)
{
    qDebug() << "there is an error";
}

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
 }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Followings are my experience with QPrinter in Linux which built on CUPS. So if you are planning to use it on Windows it might be a totally difference experience than mine. But I think error checking in Linux contains a lot of uncertainties.

I tried QPrinter::printerState() with HP 107w, it was always returning Idle even when printer is not plugged in. Same was happening with Xerox WorkCentre 3025 too. So I recommend you to not rely on QPrinter::PrinterState. Also documentation states that [QPrinter::printerState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#printerState)

> Returns the current state of the printer. This may not always be accurate (for example if the printer doesn't have the capability of reporting its state to the operating system).

I was printing to via [QPainter.begin(printer)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#begin). It only fails if printer does not connected when OS started. But once the printer available after a boot, it behaves like everything is going to be okay forever. It just queues up prints and when printer becomes available, fed up with paper, just prints everything it received before. I thought return value of [QPrinter::newPage()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#newPage) would be good place to check if there is no paper and ask user to insert papers to continue. But nah, it never returns false neither.